# Left luggage in Luxembourg with late opening times

Tags: luggage-storage, luxembourg

I would like to leave my bags somewhere in Luxembourg City at about 16:00 and pick them up at midnight. However, the [left luggage facility at the railway station](http://www.cfl.lu/espaces/voyageurs/en/gares-et-services/services/objets-trouv%C3%A9s) closes at 21:30. What are my options?

Answer (score 3):

There is a luggage store at Luxembourg train stain open 24/7 called nannybag.

It quotes:

> You transit through Luxembourg Train Station and do not know where to leave your luggage? With Nannybag's network of hotels and stores, you can find and reserve a secured luggage storage near the Luxembourg Train Station. This service is available 24/7 from €6 for 24 hours, so, do not hesitate to make the most of your day!

You can check availablity by filling out a form [here.](https://www.nannybag.com/en/luggage-storage/luxembourg/luxembourg-train-station)